# Schedule Controls for ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, components

Are there any scheduling components, commercial or otherwise, for ASP.Net MVC?  Our company currently uses the Infragistics WebSchedule controls, but they don't appear to support MVC.

**Edit:**
I think I may have been a bit unclear, I am not looking for a task scheduler, rather I am looking for a web calendar/appointment/schedule management framework or component set.  Something that would include a Month/Week/Day view of a calendar and allow me to create and display appointment items.

A framework that would let me build something like Google calendar, except the appointments would be stored in my database, not Googles.

Comment: So, which one did you choose?

Comment: dhtmlxScheduler.  It is almost a year into the project and we are very happy with them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just wanted to update with the scheduling tool we eventually choose.
[dhtmlxScheduler](http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/index.shtml) - we are very happy with both the tool and the support.

Also - since it was never mentioned in any of the answers above, Telerik has a schedule tool that is compatible with ASP.Net MVC as well.

Comment: The calendar included in their MVC suite is more of a datepicker, no?

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like:
http://www.daypilot.org/demo/Calendar/ResourcesView.aspx

Comment: DayPilot now has a MVC version of the scheduler as well: http://mvc.daypilot.org/

Answer (score 1):

It was brought to my attention that webforms could be used inside of an MVC application.

This gives the me the ability to use the Infagistics schedule components for a week/month/day views of a calendar inside of an MVC application, even though the infragistics components are not MVC compatible.

Mixing webforms in an MVC solution is an ugly solution, but at this point looks better than the alternative of trying to write my own month/week/day view appointment calendar UI.

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at Keyvan Nayyeri's Abidar 1.0: http://nayyeri.net/blog/abidar-1.0-beta-1/

Comment: This is a task scheduler, not a diary scheduler, if I'm not mistaken?