# Scheduling system or calendar for project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, calendar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Schedule Controls for ASP.Net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621410/schedule-controls-for-asp-net-mvc)

I have MVC3 in which I want to use any good scheduling system. I can spend money to purchase  if any good control. I need it for my schedules, meetings and manage events.

Anyone know any good calendar/scheduling tool for mvc3 project?

I have seen mozilla calendar at http://www.mozilla.org/projects/calendar/.Is that web based which can be used in my project. Any info on that please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't needed to use this myself yet, but I it looks promising.
http://www.web-delicious.com/jquery-events-calendar-wdcalendar/